# Selecting random entry in MySQL with WHERE clause problem

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running the following code to get a random entry from a dictionary:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_dict WHERE 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

This works great, but as soon as I expand there WHERE clause the query fails. What I need is something like...

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_dict WHERE 1 and lock='0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Can anyone point out to me where I'm going wrong? My mind has turned to peanut butter.

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you just do 
SELECT * FROM tbl_dict WHERE lock='0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

Comment: How does it fail? do you get an error, an eroneous result?

Comment: Hi Sledge, when I perform that query no data is pulled out. The data is pulled out by PHP and then sent as XML to a Flash file. For some reason the query appears dependant on the '1' that I remove and cannot augment :/

Comment: Hi Neil, the script fails gracefully by not returning a row from the table. It doesn't seem to be able to select any rows matching this (though I can assure you all of the rows are set appropriately).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lock is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) for MySQL. You have to put it in backticks (`) or double-quotes (in ansi mode) if you want to use it as an identifier.

You might also be interested in http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand.
ORDER BY Rand() might or might not be a bit too suboptimal in your case when it comes to speed.

Comment: Thank you! I was in such a rush prototyping this had completely slipped my mind, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, this is wrong for what you're trying to do.

You do have a synthetic auto_incremented id column on your table, right?

if so, then why not:

```
  select * from tbl_dict where id 
   = (select floor( rand() * ( max(b.id) + 1) ) from tabl_dict b );
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this code aside for the production version.